# Use RxJS in an Angular library

Tags: angular, rxjs

I create an angular library "mylib"

I create a service which uses BehaviorSubject Observable from rxjs.

For example

```
  currentLanguage = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
```

I have a component in mylib, which will set the language on change event on a select input.

```
this.myService.currentLanguage.next('en');
```

After building "mylib" and use in `myapp`... I can subscribe to `myService` from myapp.

If I change the value on the select input, I can see the event, yet, there is no next value sent to the BehaviorSubject and no error in the console. So I can't emit value change from the component of mylib.

Yet... if from myapp I emit a next value.. it work...

So my question is why from a component of a custom angular library it's not possible to to use "next" yet it is from the component which use the library... and it's possible from any component of the app which import the library service ?

Maybe it can be related to the @NgModule in mylib.module.ts, it's possible that I have to import rxjs in imports Array ? I try to

```
 imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, BehaviorSubject]
```

make error

an idea ? :)

Thank's

Mike

Comment: I hope this help, https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#why-list-the-same-component-in-multiple-ngmodule-properties

Comment: Do you have `myService` in the `exports` of the module declaration of `myLib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be the lib and the app are using two instances of the service.

Make sure you have "providedIn: 'root'" specified on your service.
For example:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class myService {
.....
}
```

Also make sure the service is imported using the library name from the 'dist' directory, not using a relative path.

For example:

```
import { myService } from 'myLib';
```

Comment: Yes @Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'}) is specified

Comment: How are you importing your service from the library in the app?   Import it using the library name from the 'dist' directory, not using a relative path.   Can you reproduce this in StackBlitz?

Comment: Thank's T Esh ! Was the path to the service lib... The one suggested in myapp was the wrong one ! Thank's a lot

Comment: please [edit] your answer to make it look more like an answer. ATM it looks like a comment, but since it helped the OP you want to formalize it a bit better

Comment: Edited my answer appropriately.